# Why are illegal numbers being treated as normal, when they are forbidden to?

Tags: c

I am building a small game with a soldier system where the player in certain events, gets to say a number of soldiers to be sent in battle. I have made 2 functions so that numbers above the number of available soldiers (set to 450 at start, may change within the game). Yet, on my tests when entering a bigger number nothing happens. I believe that the recursion on the second function is problematic, and I have implemented something wrong. Here is the code:

```
int wrong_soldiers_check(int soldiers)
{
    int de_facto_soldiers = give_soldiers();
    int ret_value = 0;
    if(de_facto_soldiers < soldiers){
        print_slowly("Sir! We don't have so many soldiers! Let me ask you again...");

        ret_value = 1;
    }

    return ret_value;
}

int generic_attack()
{
    int soldiers;
    print_slowly("\nAlright! How many men should we send?\n");
    print_soldiers();
    print_slowly("You: Let's send ");
    scanf("%d", &soldiers);

    int check;
    check = wrong_soldiers_check(soldiers);
    if(check == 1){
        generic_attack();
    }
    return soldiers;
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Edit:

This is the code for `give_soldiers`

```
int give_soldiers()
{
    soldiersp = fopen("soldiers.txt", "r");
    char soldiers[3];

    fgets(soldiers, 4, soldiersp);

    fclose(soldiersp);

    int soldiers_num = atoi(soldiers);

    return soldiers_num;
}
```

Comment: After the recursive call to `generic_attack()` returns, you return the original value of `soldiers`, not the value that was entered in the recursion.

Comment: Don't use recursion for this, use a loop.

Comment: @Barmar but isn't `soldiers` supposed to get a new value by using `scanf()`?

Comment: @Barmar I thought about using a loop, but I wanted to figure out what's wrong

Comment: As stated `int generic_attack()` returns a value but it is ignored by the previous calling instance. The local variable `int soldiers` is unique to *that instance* of the function. So when you recurse, `int soldiers` is a different variable.

Comment: @Weather Vane, so it gets an arbitary value?

Comment: No, it keeps the same value it already has, because it is a different variable from `soldiers` in the recursed function that is called.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ohhh I think I got it. So, not `soldiers` itself is used after recursion

Comment: So I guess you need `soldiers = generic_attack();`

Comment: @WeatherVane true. Thanks! I will implement it now

Edit: Also sorry for not picking it up immediatelly. I am not that experienced

Comment: @WeatherVane one more question. Why isn't `soldiers` just reset?

Comment: Because each recursion creates a new, different variable `soldiers`. They have no connection with each other unless you explicitly set them. As said, you don't need recursion here. But when you do, try to think of each recursive call as if to an identical function where every identifier has a `1` appended, and when that recurses again, it is to another identical function where every identifier has a `2` appended, and so on.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ok think I got it. Final question, because I want to stop being annoying: why doesn't the rest of the function run, whatever the value of `soldiers`?

Comment: It does run: it is `return soldiers;`. This is either the value you enter on this instance of recursion, or on entered at another level.

Comment: @WeatherVane but why does it skip the rest of the function?

Comment: Sorrry, I don't understand what you are asking. Your code failed to recognise the valid number of soldiers, because the caller did not collect it, as explained. You returned a correct number of soldiers that the user entered, but the caller threw it away.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am asking why the caller didn't collect it, except if I got so confused and because I am not the most cunning mind just have lost connection

Comment: The caller did not collect the new value because the code says `generic_attack();` instead of `soldiers = generic_attack();`. We are going round in circles.

Comment: @WeatherVane So it doesn't keep the starting vaule from `scanf()` consistently. Ok thanks and sorry if I was annoying

Comment: You're fine. It can be a bit difficult to wrench your mind around recursion.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks. Recursion is quite difficult. I should pick up my "The C Programming Language and do a recap"

Comment: It can be a tricky thing to understand at first, but once you grasp it a whole new vista opens up for you!

Comment: @Barmar I know! And that's why I continue. I am learning more by the day and I a happy with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah-ha!

```
int give_soldiers()
{
    soldiersp = fopen("soldiers.txt", "r"); // may not succeed in opening
    char soldiers[3]; // dimensioned for 3 characters

    fgets(soldiers, 4, soldiersp); // reading in up to 4 bytes (overflow!)

    fclose(soldiersp);

    int soldiers_num = atoi(soldiers); // should be null-terminated string, at least

    return soldiers_num;
}
```

Slightly improved...

```
int give_soldiers() {
    char *fname = "soldiers.txt"; // make name prominent
    FILE *fp = fopen( fname, "r" ); // local, so use local variable
    if( fp == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open '%s'... Exiting\n", fname );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    char str[ 32 ]; // Be generous
    str[0] = '\0'; // Is a 'string' even if source file is zero length
    fgets( str, sizeof str, fp ); // Should test for NULL return, but being optimistic and concise.

    fclose( fp );

    return atoi( str ); // fgets() insures null terminated string
}
```

Comment: I see. I understand this but I have 2 questions:

I am not very familliar with the error system so not really getting what is going on in there

What does the rt mode in `fopen` do?

Comment: @a573263 Instead of giving you a fish, gonna teach you how to fish... Read the manual and develop the habit of doing that sort of self-learning. :-) Hope you are on your way... :-)

Comment: Fair enough. Will be back in a jiffy with my answers

Comment: I did my research and this is what I got: stderr is the standard errror message that prints error messages in the console. Its difference with stdout is that it can't transport the message to the file itself, while stdout can @Fe2O3

Comment: I also searched `exit`. While it said some stuff I couldn't get, but what I understood is that it just closes everything

Comment: Update: I changed give soldiers and it works now!!! Thanks soo much! You have just made a person's day 100 times better :) Thanks to all the people who helped!!!

Comment: @a573263 The words, "It works now" is why most of us are here... Glad to help... Re: `stderr`: There are, by default, two ways to output: `stdout` and `stderr`... `printf(`)` always uses `stdout`. 'fprintf( )` directs output where the code says. `fprintf( stdout, ...)` is equivalent to `printf( ...` If code encounters an error, better to write it to 'stderr` in case the command line has redirected output to a file (eg: "cat file1 > file2"... The error message won't be hidden inside the file, but will be written to the console. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Programming, even though I am not the best at it (and will never be) is really good for me. I just feel really good when doing it. And the moment you can say "it works now" is priceless! I also have to thank you for motivating me to learn at least 2 new things: stderr and exit. I will make good use of them! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The natural way to write your `generic_attack()` function would be to use a loop.  For example:

```
int generic_attack() {
    int soldiers;

    do {
        print_slowly("\nAlright! How many men should we send?\n");
        print_soldiers();
        print_slowly("You: Let's send ");
        scanf("%d", &soldiers);
    } while (wrong_soldiers_check(soldiers) == 1);

    return soldiers;
}
```

It would be hard to make the function much clearer than that, and "clear" is among the top measures of code quality.

As for the actual question of what is wrong with the original code, it is as described in comments: that version always returns the value read by the `scanf()` in the initial execution, regardless of whether it recurses or what any of the recursive executions of the function do.  This is in part because every *execution* of a function gets its own local variables (except `static` ones), even recursive executions.

In particular, the `soldiers` variable into which a recursive execution of your original function reads input is a different variable (with a different storage location if you tested that) than the same named-variable of the calling execution of the same function.  The caller ignores the return value of the recursive call.  Another way to fix the function, then, would be to stop ignoring the return value of the recursive call:

```
int generic_attack() {
{
    int soldiers;

    print_slowly("\nAlright! How many men should we send?\n");
    print_soldiers();
    print_slowly("You: Let's send ");
    scanf("%d", &soldiers);

    if (wrong_soldiers_check(soldiers) == 1) {
        // NOTE: the value returned by the recursive call is returned by this function
        return generic_attack();
    } else {
        return soldiers;
    }
}
```

But don't actually do that.  Recursion is the wrong tool for most jobs, including this one.

---

Now that you have posted the code for `give_soldiers()`, it is clear that you have another, separate problem as well.  As [@Fe2O3 observed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73480804/2402272), that function has a potential buffer overflow.  It's not clear to me why you're reading the number of available soldiers from a file every time -- that seems awfully wasteful -- but you're not gaining anything by manually buffering it.  This would be simpler:

```
#define SOLDIERS_FILE "soldiers.txt"

// ...

int give_soldiers() {
    // Note: no need for a global variable here:
    FILE *soldiersp = fopen(SOLDIERS_FILE, "r");
    // check for NULL ...

    int soldiers_num;
    int num_fields = fscanf(soldiersp, "%d", &soldiers_num);
    fclose(soldiersp);

    // handle error if num_fields != 1 ...

    return soldiers_num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"What have I done wrong?" You've tried to use recursion to solve a problem without understanding the consequences.

If you want to 'restart' the same function, you can use `goto` and a `label`

```
int generic_attack() {
    int soldiers;
top:
    print_slowly("\nAlright! How many men should we send?\n");
    print_soldiers();
    print_slowly("You: Let's send ");
    scanf("%d", &soldiers);

    int check;
    check = wrong_soldiers_check(soldiers);
    if(check == 1){
        goto top;
    }
    return soldiers;
}
```

Or, slightly more brief with a small rearrangement:

```
int generic_attack() {
top:
    print_slowly("\nAlright! How many men should we send?\n");
    print_soldiers();
    print_slowly("You: Let's send ");

    int soldiers;
    scanf("%d", &soldiers);
    if( wrong_soldiers_check( soldiers ) )
        goto top;

    return soldiers;
}
```

Since it's a game, you want the program's responses to be less like a program's logic. I'm just having fun here... Another possibility using 'goto'

```
int generic_attack() {
    int soldiers;
    print_slowly("\nAlright! How many men should we send?\n");
    print_soldiers();
top:
    print_slowly("You: Let's send ");
    scanf("%d", &soldiers);

    // int wrong_soldiers_check(int soldiers) code spliced in here.
    int available = give_soldiers();
    if( soldiers > available ) {
        print_slowly("Sir! We don't have so many soldiers! Enter again...");
        goto top;
    }
    if( soldiers == available ) {
        print_slowly("Sir! There'll be no-one left to drive you! Enter again...");
        goto top;
    }
    return soldiers;
}
```

Other people have suggested using one of C's looping operations. If you did, the final example's `goto` could be replaced with `continue;`

Many ways to skin a cat!

You can see where this snippet could also be used in the function. (Since no-one would suspect the user might enter "-42" when asked...)

```
top:
    print_slowly("You: Let's send ");
    scanf("%d", &soldiers);

    if( soldiers < 1) {
        print_slowly("Ah, you mean let the enemy become complacent!\nInteresting...\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // int wrong_soldiers_check(int soldiers) code spliced in here.
    int available = give_soldiers();
```

Comment: Or a `while(check)` loop with `int check=1;` above the loop.  `int generic_attack() { int soldiers; int check=1; while (check == 1){ print_slowly("\nAlright! How many men should we send?\n"); print_soldiers(); print_slowly("You: Let's send "); scanf("%d", &soldiers); check = wrong_soldiers_check(soldiers); } return soldiers; }`

Comment: Well, I avoid goto, but I had it as a solution in case nothing else works. Anyways thank you

Comment: @a573263 'goto' has a bad reputation, but, in some instances (like this) it is clear, simple and straightforward. You make use of what you can make use of to write clear, concise code.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I agree. I have already used it once more within the game. I felt like it would be a bit bad if I did it again and I should it at all costs

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Yes, could be done with `while`, `for` or `do/while`, but that imposes a level of indentation that is, perhaps, unnecessary. All good. Many ways to skin a cat! :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3 really true. I have been offered at least 2 ways of implementing this  and I am sure there are even more

Comment: I completely agree that `goto` has appropriate uses.  But this is not one of them.  The situation is natural for a `do` ... `while` loop, however (which is a primary reason *why* it is inappropriate for `goto`).

Comment: @JohnBollinger While `do/while()` seems appropriate, this 'goto' solution makes it possible to enclose the 'wrong_soldiers()` processing within the body of `generic_attack()`, and could eliminate the need for `wrong()` as a helper function. With `do/while`, one could do the same, but that would require a flag to be set/cleared/tested... It's as broad as it is long. In this instance (within one function) `goto` is a clean, simple solution...

Comment: @Fe2O3, that's a solution without a problem.  One could debate the hypothetical of whether factoring the soldier-number check into its own function would have been preferable in service to avoiding a `goto`, but that is not the situation actually at hand.  The choice to factor it out was made as a separate consideration.  *The code you have presented* would be improved by replacing the `goto` with a `do` / `while` loop.

Comment: @JohnBollinger A problem may arise if one has to scroll through source to see what the helper function is doing, then scroll back again. You know code is read many time more often than it is written... This goto is more than adequate, and the blending-in of the code of the helper function (elimination of a function) makes this code better. You are entitled to your differing opinion, of course.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I love that in your gamey implementation you added "There will be no one left to drive you"! lol. You truly are a a gamer

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Pushing control-flow into flags is just as bad as using goto when there is a perfectly fine structured way to do it.

Comment: `int generic_attack() { print_slowly("\nAlright! How many men should we send?\n"); print_soldiers(); for (;;) { print_slowly("You: Let's send "); int soldiers; scanf("%d", &soldiers); // int wrong_soldiers_check(int soldiers) code spliced in here. int available = give_soldiers(); if( soldiers < available ) return soldiers;  print_slowly(soldiers > available ? "Sir! We don't have so many soldiers! Enter again..." : "Sir! There'll be no-one left to drive you! Enter again..."); } }`

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes... Many ways to skin a cat... Thanks...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I have bad news... tried all of the solutions I was offered (both loops and goto) and haven't gotten a correct response yet... I am starting to get angry-sad over this

Comment: Perhaps you will post the code (Edit the question highlighting the edit) of `give_soldiers()` All answers have been based on the presumption that `give_soldiers()` returns a positive value > 0... Or, debug it yourself printing the returned value in your code and figure out what that function is returning for comparison. AND, there are MANY problems reported with using `scanf()`... Whatever happened BEFORE this function may have left garbage that this function tries to convert to an integer value.

Comment: @Fe2O3 ok I will post `give_soldiers()` now

Comment: @Fe2O3 I tried debugging manually with togo solution and it doens't even allow me to type. It is constantly printing the messages that follow an illlegal number

Comment: @JohnBollinger "@Fe2O3, that's a solution without a problem."... Turns out that the code of an unseen helper function was ALSO incorrect and causing grief. All the solutions posted `presumed` that `give_soldiers()` was returning a value > 0... It's hard to be right when there are incorrect presumptions and blinkered approaches....

Comment: @Deduplicator Slow night. Just revisiting your suggestion. While it DOES solve the problem, if posted as a solution, there would be great "writhing and gnashing of teeth" over the idea of "returning from the middle of a function when it is not an error condition."... Ya can't please everyone... Cheers! :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3 thanks for reminding me! XD I have made a mechanism for when having 0 soldiers but forgot the user might input negatives! Thanks!